# Windows 8 Wifi connections freeze randomly

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi

I'm using a relatively new SONY Vaio Laptop to connect to a Linux machine (a Raspberry Pi on the local network) and I am having the problem, that the connection seems to freeze at larger (not too large, about a few KB) amount of data. I've experienced this in two cases:

1) I am connecting via SSH (Putty or cygwin) and the connection freezing when commands on the linux machine produce larger output, e.g. when editing files in emacs or executing a "find .". The SSH session then freezes in the middle of the output. It's not that the SSH session seems to get terminated, but rather it simply hangs and I have to reconnect.

2) I am running an Apache on the machine and I can access a simple, small index.html file, but for example I cannot access a larger css-file. The network console of my browser just says "pending" for that request. In the access-log of the apache I can see a status 200 for that request, but the file is not transmitted.

When I use a wired connection (instead of wifi) it just works. And even when I connect with my mobile via Wifi it also works.

So it seems to be a WIFI related issue. I mentioned that I'm using a newer VAIO Laptop as it seems, that there might be some wifi related issues with these devices. The problem also appears when I use a USB Wifi dongle instead of the integrated wifi chip. I'm using Windows 8.

Ideas anybody?

Comment: This a new problem of something that always happened because the Rpi is a great device just not seeing it as an access point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening to me, and I believe I found the solution ...

Either type:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 1454
```

or, in your `/etc/network/interfaces` file, add the line `mtu 1454` to make it look similar to this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.50
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1
    mtu 1454
```

Then restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown eth0
sudo ifup eth0
```

I'd recommend the second way, otherwise you have to run the first command on every restart

Comment: This solved the problem. Thank you really much!